# Warning : Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:]

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i Generate pdf dynamically.. 
I make the pages from string retrieved from database ..

when i open that pdf in webview... but when i zoom in zoom out pdf .. i got memory warning and another warning as "Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active" and after some time it crash

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` is itself a very heavy component, and with the pdf,it is more disastrous.

Make use of `QuartzCore Framework` to process your pdf.

Secondly,the warning `Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:]`

From what I have seen, `UIWebView` does not play well with others. For gesture recognizers, you could try returning YES from:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

Hope it helps..